# Where viewstate value is stored on the client side in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

An ASP.Net website that need to be accessed from C# code, but I don't understand the whole viewstate concept in details.

There is a button that execute such a javascript onclick event `javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions ...`

This makes POST request. One of the fields being posted is viewstate `&__VIEWSTATE=`

Where it's value comes from, I can't seems to find complete and clear explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The view state is a collection of values where server controls store information that they need. A text box for example stores the previous value in the view state, so that it can check after the postback if the value was changed by the user.

The view state for all controls is encoded and put in a single hidden field in the page. After the postback the view state is decoded so that the (recreated) controls have the same information as when the page was created.

The regular way for the user to make a postback is to press a button (which is an `input` with `type=submit`). That will automatically include information about which button was pressed in the data that is posted to the server. The JavaScript that is used to do a postback will simulate this behaviour, i.e. add information about which control was used to make the postback.